# access elements of a directory by ID in zshell

Tags: directory, alias, zsh

I would like to know, whether it is possible to access the elements which "ls" returns by an ID additionally to  their name. I am using z-shell.
What I am thinking of is something like the following

```
>> ls_modified
A/  B/  C/  d.txt
1  2  3  4
```

So I can access them in the next step by

```
>> cd_modified 2
```

or

```
>> vim_modified 4
```

I already have found some workaround to access the last element that gets printed by "ls -ltr" which is the following alias:

```
cdlast='cd *(.om[1])'
vlast='vim *(.om[1])'
```

As I have never really worked in my .zshrc I am not sure whether I can simply adapt the above code to work with an Integer as input. Also I would really like to see the ID listed for every element so I know which one I am accessing.

If there is any way to realize this, I would be very thankful.

Also I don't really know which Tags to use.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to achieve this with ZSH 'globbing' or 'filename generation' features

- `*` : all files and directory in the current working directory
- `*(.)` : only regular files, not directories
- `*(.om)` : only regular files, ordered by modification date
- `*(.om[2])` : the second most recently modified regular file

See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation for the complete info.

If you want to access the second directory, ordered by name (the default) use `*(/[2])`.

To pass in the index as a parameter, you can use a shell function.

```
 function cd_modified { cd *(/[$1]) }
```

Comment: Thanks! Then I will use `cd *(/om[$1]) ` to access the directories sorted by date.
But what about the `ls_modified` command? Can I show the ID for the directories?

Comment: Here's a possible solution, although the output will be a bit different then in your example `function ls_modified { ls_arr=(\`ls\`) ; for (( i=1 ; i<= $#ls_arr ; i++ )) ; do echo -e "$i\t${ls_arr[i]}" ; done }`